# does an explicit formula for GCD exist?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

i was trying to put GCD(a,b) into the form of f(a,b) = a +5b. i know the euclidean algorithm finds the GCD, so I was trying to put that concept into a recursive formula but its getting way too complicated (T(a,b)= max(a,b)mod(min(a,b) then I would have to divide by remainders, etc.). can GCD be simplified into a formula or am I trying to prove something impossible?

Comment: The Euclidean algorithm is already a recursive formula.  Are you asking for a multiplicative formula instead of an additive one?

Comment: either-- I don't know how to write the euclidean algorithm as a recursive formula, which is usually in the form T(n) = aT(n/b) +... I only know the steps to use the algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest step expression of the Euclidean algorithm is

$$r_{k}=r_{k-2}-q\cdot r_{k-1}$$

When we get $r_n=0$ then we return $r_{n-1}$ as the result of the algorithm.

In particular, $q=\left[\dfrac{r_{k-2}}{r_{k-1}}\right]$ at each step, where $[x]$ is the largest integer less than or equal to $x$:

$$r_{k}=r_{k-2}-r_{k-1}\left[\frac{r_{k-2}}{r_{k-1}}\right]$$